# Edit a file on a docker container of a Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a Docker swarm of a dozen service.
For debug purpose, I sometimes need to edit a python file on one of the containers. In order for the container to take the changes into account, I then need to run:

```
docker restart <container_id>
```

However, whenever I run this command, a new container of the same image is created, which is troublesome in my case, as only the most recent container matters. **The restart_policy is set to NO**.

What is the best way to solve my issue? How would you edit a container in a swarm?

Comment: Why dont you use source filename to apply changes once you edited file?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean? As I don't have nano, vim, vi in my containers, I run docker cp to update the file that I want to change

Comment: I'd build and test the change locally; run it in a local non-Swarm Docker environment if needed; commit to source control; have my CI system build a new image; and then deploy it.  Cluster environments like Swarm or Kubernetes really aren't good day-to-day development setups.